# how to transform live RTMP video to live mp3 Icecast stream

Tags: audio, rtmp, icecast

I have RTMP live stream with video and audio. 
I can get ogg audio live stream from RTMP and translate it to Icecast2 and get it on my site using JPlayer. 
Now i use such command:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://192.168.22.12/live/live1 \
-vn -acodec libvorbis -b:a 48k -f ogg - | oggfwd -p -d "" \
-g "" -u "" localhost 8000 somepass live2
```

Then I stream my live audio using Icecast2, but it is in OGG format, so mobile devices don't play it (Android device has a time lagging near 30 sec before they start playing, iOS devices don't want to play it).

How can I transcode it to mp3 before sending to Icecast2?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a (very) recent version you just could use ffmpeg for this.
To test if your ffmpeg is capable to stream to Icecast, do the following:

```
ffmpeg -protocols -v 0 | grep icecast
```

If this returns "icecast", hooray, you can just do the following:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://192.168.22.12/live/live1 -vn \
       -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 64k -f mp3 \
       -content_type audio/mpeg \
       icecast://source:pass@example.com:8000/mountpoint.mp3
```

Replace `source` with a specific username, if you have configured any, else leave it as source. The other things should be obvious.

Comment: If you use an older version, add ` live=1` in the input URL, e.g.:
 `-i "rtmp://192.168.22.12/live/live1 live=1"` and if you use Debian 8, install libav-tools and replace `ffmpeg` with `avconv`

Comment: what is `source:pass` ?

Comment: The Icecast source user and password.